# Bad request(error #400) in streaming dataset

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am using Powershell script to upload data every minute into streaming dataset in PowerBI(It's scheduled with Windows Task Scheduler). 
I'm struggling with strange error, that appeared without changing anything.

This is my code:

```
function invokeRest()
{  


$endpoint = "https://api.powerbi.com/beta/..."

$query = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select * from LS.dbo.live_Holdbacks;" -ServerInstance $env:computername)

$RetArray = @()

Foreach ($row in $query) {    
      $payload = @{
            "id" = $row.LiveHoldbackID
            "RefreshDate" = $row.RefreshDate.ToString("HH:mm")
            "CreatedBy" = $row.CreatedBy
            "Campaign Code" = $row.CampaignCode 
            "Campaign Description" = $row.CampaignDescription
            "Comment" = $row.Comment 
            "Customer Number" = $row.CustomerNumber 
            "Country" = $row.Country
            "holdback" = $row.holdback
            "upselling" = $row.upselling 

      }
      $RetArray += $payload
}

Write-Host (ConvertTo-Json @($RetArray));
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json @($RetArray)) -Verbose

}


function ClearDataset([string]$authToken)
{
    Clear-PBITableRows -authToken $authToken -dataSetName "DEV_live_holdbacks_no_History_1min" -tableName "RealTimeData" -Verbose 
}


Import-Module -Name PowerBIPS

$authToken = Get-PBIAuthToken -ClientId "...." -Credential (new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("......",(ConvertTo-SecureString -String "...." -AsPlainText -Force)))
$group = Get-PBIGroup -authToken $authToken -name "..."
Set-PBIGroup -id $group.id
$dataSets = Get-PBIDataSet -authToken $authToken -name "DEV_live_holdbacks_no_History_1min" -includeTables -Verbose
#ClearDataset $authToken

    try {
        ClearDataset $authToken
        invokeRest 
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host 'Sth goes bad'
        Write-Host $_
        # do something with $_, log it, more likely
    }
```

API info is taken directly from PowerBI, every URL is ok, and everything that I got in console is this:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

It just suddenly stopped working... Anyone got idea how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out! The problem was related to one of fields - it's type was set to Number and there was string passed into it.